# Could someone help me understand the ambiguity here in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update, npgsql

So I've been trying out PG for a few days, specifically through NpgSQL in dotnet core, but I don't believe that is relevant to my question.  I've been writing a couple of update functions.  The first one was easy:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Api"."UpdateExpenseReceipt" ( "vReceiptID" UUID  , "vTotal" DOUBLE PRECISION , "vTaxPercent" DOUBLE PRECISION , "vShippingCost" DOUBLE PRECISION , "vReceiptDate" TIMESTAMP , "vReference" VARCHAR , "vCurrentToken" UUID )
        RETURNS TABLE ( ReceiptID UUID , Total DOUBLE PRECISION , TaxPercent DOUBLE PRECISION , ShippingCost DOUBLE PRECISION , Reference VARCHAR(96) , ReceiptDate TIMESTAMP )
        LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
        AS $$
        DECLARE "iValidReceipt" INTEGER;
        DECLARE "iValidUser" INTEGER;
        BEGIN
        
            "iValidReceipt" := ( SELECT COUNT("ReceiptID") FROM "Users"."ExpenseReceipt" WHERE "ReceiptID" = "vReceiptID" );
            "iValidUser"  := ( SELECT COUNT("AccountID") FROM "Users"."Account" WHERE "CurrentToken" = "vCurrentToken" LIMIT 1 );
        
            IF "iValidUser" = 0 THEN
                RAISE 'Error' USING ERRCODE = '10001';
            END IF;
        
            IF "iValidReceipt" > 0 THEN
                UPDATE "Users"."ExpenseReceipt" SET
                    "Total" = COALESCE( "vTotal" , "Total" )
                    , "TaxPercent" = COALESCE( "vTaxPercent" , "TaxPercent" )
                    , "ShippingCost" = COALESCE( "vShippingCost" , "ShippingCost" )
                    , "Reference" = COALESCE( CAST( "vReference" AS VARCHAR ) , "Reference" )
                    , "ReceiptDate" = COALESCE( "vReceiptDate" , "ReceiptDate" )
                    , "EditDate" = current_timestamp at time zone 'utc'
                WHERE "ReceiptID" = "vReceiptID";
                
                RETURN QUERY
                SELECT
                    "ReceiptID"
                    , "Total"
                    , "TaxPercent"
                    , "ShippingCost"
                    , "Reference"
                    , "ReceiptDate"
                FROM "Users"."ExpenseReceipt"
                WHERE "ReceiptID" = "vReceiptID";
            ELSE
                RAISE 'Error' USING ERRCODE = '10101';
            END IF;
        
        
        END; $$

--I'll include the table itself in case its relevant
CREATE TABLE "Users"."ExpenseReceipt"
(
    "ReceiptID" UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "AccountID" UUID NOT NULL ,
    "Total" DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL ,
    "TaxPercent" DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0.0 ,
    "ShippingCost" DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0.0 ,
    "Reference" VARCHAR(96) ,
    "ReceiptDate" TIMESTAMP ,
    "EditDate" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT ( current_timestamp at time zone 'utc' )
);
```

Easy update function, uses coalesce to not update the value if the API call doesn't set them.  Everything works fine (after dealing through the numerous naming issues I've run into with postgres, and there I think NpgSQL is relevant).  I know how to get it right.  I made a second one, basically exactly the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Api"."UpdateSupplyItem" ( "vItemID" UUID , "vDescription" VARCHAR , "vSize" VARCHAR , "vNetCost" DOUBLE PRECISION , "vPackageQuantity" DOUBLE PRECISION , "vNetWeight" DOUBLE PRECISION , "vCurrentToken" UUID )
RETURNS TABLE ( "ItemID" UUID , "Description" VARCHAR , "Size" VARCHAR , "NetCost" DOUBLE PRECISION , "PackageQuantity" DOUBLE PRECISION , "NetWeight" DOUBLE PRECISION )
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE "iValidItem" INTEGER;
DECLARE "iValidUser" INTEGER;
BEGIN

    "iValidItem" := ( SELECT COUNT(usi."ItemID") FROM "Users"."SupplyItem" usi WHERE usi."ItemID" = "vItemID" );
    "iValidUser" := ( SELECT COUNT("AccountID") FROM "Users"."Account" WHERE "CurrentToken" = "vCurrentToken" LIMIT 1 );

    IF "iValidUser" = 0 THEN
        RAISE 'Error' USING ERRCODE = '10001';
    END IF;

    IF "iValidItem" > 0 THEN

        UPDATE "Users"."SupplyItem"
        SET 
             "Description" = COALESCE( "vDescription" , "Users"."SupplyItem"."Description" )
            , "Size" = COALESCE( "vSize" , "Users"."SupplyItem"."Size" ) 
            , "NetCost" = COALESCE( "vNetCost" ,  "Users"."SupplyItem"."NetCost" ) 
            , "PackageQuantity" = COALESCE( "vPackageQuantity" ,  "Users"."SupplyItem"."PackageQuantity") 
            , "NetWeight" = COALESCE( "vNetWeight" ,  "Users"."SupplyItem"."NetWeight" )
        WHERE  "Users"."SupplyItem"."ItemID" = "vItemID";

        RETURN QUERY SELECT usi."ItemID" , usi."Description" , usi."Size" , usi."NetCost" , usi."PackageQuantity" , usi."NetWeight" FROM "Users"."SupplyItem" usi WHERE usi."ItemID" = "vItemID" LIMIT 1;

    ELSE
        RAISE 'Error' USING ERRCODE = '10401';
    END IF;

END; $$


--Again, the table in case it helps

CREATE TABLE "Users"."SupplyItem"
(
    "ItemID" UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() ,
    "AccountID" UUID NOT NULL ,
    "Description" VARCHAR , 
    "Size" VARCHAR ,
    "NetCost" DOUBLE PRECISION , 
    "PackageQuantity" DOUBLE PRECISION ,
    "NetWeight" DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

but it's quite different.  You can see clearly that I've had to fully qualify the right hand side of every equals (where the earlier function had no need).  I get ambiguity all the way down the update statement.  It starts at ItemID, then Description, then Size... every attribute I think.  First thing I did was alias the table

```
UPDATE usi [...] FROM "Users"."SupplyItem" usi
```

but that failed because you can't do short aliasing in an UPDATE in PG (relation usi."[...]" does not exist") which actually kind of sucks.  I only figured out that it needed to be fully qualified when someone asked a similar question and the answer was "It must be a quirk of RETURNS TABLE."

So why is my second update "a quirk" but my first update works perfectly?  I've had a tough time with PG (and I'm not a slouch), but having two functions that seem identical having entirely different results (*at runtime no less*) makes me uncomfortable.  I'm posting here because I know the two functions must be markedly different; 99.9% of the time, there is no such thing as a "quirk."  There is something I need to understand to work around to avoid in the future.  What is the "gotcha" that I've missed in the second UPDATE function?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: I believe that @horse_with_no_name and would avoid it if I could.  But I just can't see designing in all lower case.  It's unreadable.  I would have left it alone if I could depend on every interface handling postgres the same, but Azure Data Studio and HeidiSQL handle them utterly differently.  ADS doesn't implicitly quote (and I think implicitly lower-cases in queries), but HeidiSQL implicitly double quotes (a column you name ItemID in Heidi will be "ItemID").  It's maddening, but at least this way I can be consistent and still read the list of objects in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a function variable `"Size"` (an `OUT` parameter defined in the `RETURNS TABLE` clause) and a column `"Size"` in `"Users"."SupplyItem"`. So you have to qualify the reference to indicate what you mean.

I recommend using an alias for simplicity:

```
UPDATE "Users"."SupplyItem" AS si
   SET "Size" = COALESCE("vSize" , si."Size")
...
```

There is no such ambiguity in your first example, because you didn't double quote the parameter `TaxPercent`, so it gets case folded to `taxpercent` and is different from the column `"TaxPercent"`.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz.  I'm forced to wonder if Size is a special case.  The first function I pasted in works perfectly, again all attributes are named in the RETURNS but there is no ambiguity nor ALIASing nor fully qualifying.  While I don't think my question is answered as asked (what is the difference which caused one success and on failure), I do thank you for the correct syntax for aliased update.  For anyone transitioning from MS-SQL who would try

        UPDATE usi SET usi.[Attribute] FROM "Users"."SupplyItem" usi WHERE (1=1)

Laurenz has provided the correct syntax.

Comment: I forgot to add an important detail that should make it clear.

Comment: I see your edit - you're right.  Every attribute in the RETURNs of the second example.  I should have caught that.  If I laid it out attribute-per-line for clarity, its possible I would have.  Thank you!  Again it comes back to naming! (And inconsistent styling which is my fault).

Comment: Also, I dont think you need the two scalars and the `IF()`. These would fit in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser I don't strictly need them for the WHERE but I want to throw a custom error and I didn't feel like putting a big long IF parameter that was hard to read.  I'd hope that there wouldn't be a great deal of overhead there.